# Difference between apache URI class (org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI) and jdk URI class (java.net.URI)

Tags: java, apache

What are the difference between apache URI class and jdk URI class? Both of them claim to have format of URI as defined in RFC 2396, are there some known difference between the two. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you check out the respective JavaDoc to find your answer.  Just to save you a trip to google...

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The javadoc does not explicitly say what the difference between them is.